# SVG background image in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I am using react-native-svg in order to add SVG image to my react native project. However I am struggling regarding how can I set that image as a background image in my components. I couldn't find any resources for solving this issue.

I tried something similar but it just displays the SVG without the content inside.

```
import Autentificare from '../../../assets/Autentificare.svg';

class Login extends React.Component {
 render() {
<Autentificare>
<View>....</View>
</Autentificare>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may put your svg inside a container whose position is absolute

```
return (
  <View>
    <View
      style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
    >
      <Autentificare />
    </View>
    <View>...</View>
  </View>
);
```